# set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH not working with Android Toolchain

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, cmake

I am porting a CMake C and C++ game to Android using the Android CMake Toolchain.

The library dependencies for the project are stored in `PROJECTDIR/android_dependencies` and I have added the following code to the CMake file to use them (I checked that the directories and files exist).

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/android_dependencies/${ANDROID_ABI}")
```

But my project still says it could not find the dependencies like OpenAL (all the libraries are copied).

If I copy the libraries to `$NDK/platforms/android-9/usr/lib` and include files to `$NDK/platforms/android-9/usr/include` the project compiles correctly.

What could I be doing wrong ?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Comment: Which **exact** toolchain do you use? Looks like it sets [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY.html) to `ONLY`, so all library search paths are prepended by sysroot.

Comment: The one in $NDK/build/cmake/Android.toolchin.cmake  . I downloaded the NDK and CMake (for NDK , I installed the other one from Kitware website) using Android Studio SDK Manager

Comment: @Tsyvarev I set CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY and CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE to both in the CMake file and now it works. Can you add your comment as an answer

Comment: didn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: @Nimitz14 CMake version ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Almost all toolchains set variable [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) variable. This variable, aside other things, may add additional "root" to paths, used by `find_*` CMake commands. But by default also "non-rooted" paths are searched too.

Some toolchains may set variable(s) `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_*`, which adjust behavior of `CMAKE_SYSROOT` when search things.

E.g., setting variable [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY.html) to `ONLY` makes `find_library` to search **only** "rooted" paths, so one *cannot find libraries located on the host*. (There are exceptions from this rule, see [documentation for find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) for more details).

Script `CMakeLists.txt` is able to change value of `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_*` variables, and set them to `BOTH` (or just clear them). But generally this may break toolchain (so other `find_library` calls will find something on host while they are intended to not find anything at all).

Preferred way is to follow toolchain strategy and install all package's prerequesites into sysroot before building the package itself.