# CMake: Find file not located despite file existing?

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

Really confusing CMake issue going on in my life right now.
For some reason when I am attempting to crosscompile, my find_library and find_file calls fail to find a specific file at a specific path. Find_file was added as a sanity check, which has only made me lose more sanity.

Here's a paraphrased example since I do not have rights to post the real CMakeLists:

```
set(mylib_lib_dir_release /home/myuser/mylib/lib/Release)

FIND_LIBRARY(mylib_opt mylib PATHS ${mylib_lib_dir_release} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
FIND_FILE(mylib_filepath libmylib.a PATHS ${mylib_lib_dir_release} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

if (EXISTS "/home/myuser/mylib/lib/Release/libmylib.a")
   message("IT'S REALLY THERE!")
endif()
```

When compiling normally, all three are positive results (find_library, find_file, and EXISTS all locate the file). However during cross-compilation with an ARM toolchain, neither find_library nor find_file locate the file BUT `IT'S REALLY THERE!` is printed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Symptoms are very similar to ones in [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054495/set-cmake-prefix-path-not-working-with-android-toolchain). Looks like toolchain you use forces prepending of search paths with sysroot.

Comment: In your paraphrased example, your paths are not coherent: you are searching in `/home/myuser/mylib/lib/Release`, while checking `/home/myuser/mylib/lib/**LinuxArm**/Release`

Comment: @wasthishelpful Thanks for pointing that out. Was chopping up the actual file and missed some.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you sir! That was the ticket. The path was find root path was incorrectly set.

Comment: I recently discovered the cmake options   ``--debug-output``, ``--trace``, and ``--trace-expand`` and found them helpful in understanding mysterious problems with my cmake logic.