# CMake not finding .so library

Tags: android-studio, linker, cmake

I've read several threads (and docs) on including `.so` libraries with CMake, but it doesn't appear to me that I've fallen into the errors that I've read about, namely:

- supplying an incorrect library name
- specifying an incorrect path

So what am I doing amiss? I'm working in Android Studio, and I have a cmake file in my `app` directory. It can find some things but not the .so file in question, whose path is:

```bsh
app/src/main/cpp/libusb-android-open2/android/libs/armeabi/libusb1.0.so
```

Here's my cmake file:

```
# This succeeds
add_library( demo-libusb SHARED src/main/cpp/demo-libusb.cpp )

# This succeeds
find_library( log-lib log )
if (log-lib)
    message(WARNING "HAS loglib") # This message gets printed
else(log-lib)
    message(SEND_ERROR "NO loglib")
endif(log-lib)

# This fails
link_directories( src/main/cpp/libusb-android-open2/android/libs/armeabi )
find_library( usb-lib NAMES usb1.0 libusb1.0.so )
if ( usb-lib )
    message(WARNING "HAS libusb")
else( usb-lib )
    message(SEND_ERROR "NO libusb") # This message gets printed
endif( usb-lib )
```

I have also tried:

```
find_library( usb-lib NAMES libusb1.0.so usb1.0 PATHS 
    src/main/cpp/libusb-android-open2/android/libs/armeabi
    src/main/cpp/libusb-android-open2/android/libs/armeabi-v7a
)
```

Comment: You've read this [CMake wiki article](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Using_external_libraries_that_CMake_doesn.27t_yet_have_modules_for), aren't you ?

Comment: @agg3l : I have viewed that, but perhaps you could elucidate a bit, as I'm unclear on how to proceed? First, I'm not working with a package, but with an `.so` file that I was obliged to cross-compile myself. Second, can you tell me what the meaning of `LibXML++_LIBRARIES` is? Is it supposed to be a directory? A list of `.so` files?

Comment: Is find_library working with absolute values for PATH?

Comment: @Th.Thielemann : No.

Answer (score 0):

Command `link_directories` **doesn't affect** on `find_library` search paths.

You may use *PATH* or *HINT* options for `find_library`, or set variables which are explicitely noted in its [search algorithm](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html).

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean, for example, running `cmake` with a `-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/markham/DroidEar/app/src/main/cpp/libusb-android-open2/android/libs/armeabi`? I've tried that with no better success, I'm afraid.

Comment: I've also tried specifying `PATHS` and `NAMES` in my `find_library` call. I've updated my OP to indicate the complete call with these parameters.

Comment: According to your another comment, you perform *cross-compiling*. Take a look into similar question about paths: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054495/set-cmake-prefix-path-not-working-with-android-toolchain/40080575#40080575.